# DSP processor word size

Tags: c, signal-processing

I want to implement something for this DSP proccessor.
http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BELASIGNA300-D.PDF here is its datasheet..

Here is one of the functions that i want to implement.. all variables are 16 bit int except mem[j] which is 32 bit int(on my computer).(fixed point arithmetic)
It is a IIR filter (Direct Form 2 Transposed)

Looking at pages 15-16 i dont know whether i can store the int32. Because i see different bus sizes.. 48,24,32..

If it is 24 then it wont work because mem[j] values exceed 24 bits...
It has 56bit accumulator so that is ok but i dont know whether this can be stored at memory(32 bits or 48 from the accumulator)..
I dont have the evaluation board yet and documents.

So my question is whether it supports more than 24 bits or there is a modification at code i could do...

```
void filter_mem16(const spx_word16_t *x, const spx_coef_t *num, const spx_coef_t *den, spx_word16_t *y, int N, int ord, spx_mem_t *mem, char *stack)
    {
       int i,j;
       spx_word16_t xi,yi,nyi;          

       for (i=0;i<N;i++)
       {
          xi= x[i];
          //yi=saturate (x[i]+mem[0]>>13) 
          yi = EXTRACT16(SATURATE(ADD32(EXTEND32(x[i]),PSHR32(mem[0],LPC_SHIFT)),32767));

          //nyi=-yi
          nyi = NEG16(yi);
          for (j=0;j<ord-1;j++)
          {
             //mem[j]= (num[j] *xi + mem[j+1]) + den[j] * nyi
             mem[j] = MAC16_16(MAC16_16(mem[j+1], num[j],xi), den[j],nyi);            

          }

          //mem[ord-1]=(num[ord-1] * xi)  +   (den[ord-1] *nyi)
          mem[ord-1] = ADD32(MULT16_16(num[ord-1],xi), MULT16_16(den[ord-1],nyi));        

          y[i] = yi;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably supports 32 bit integers- it will just do the processing slower, so you should minimize the number of 32 bit ints and 32 bit int operations.

The data sheet says that the chip has a dedicated IDE.  The IDE documentation and/or the compiler should be able to tell you if 32 bit ints are supported or not.